# Rails redirect_to Unless In the Process of Purchasing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, devise

So I have a rails app that uses Koudoku to handle subscription purchases and devise for users.  I'd like my users to be redirected to a dashboard page when they login, unless they're in the process of purchasing a subscription.

Here's the problem...

When a visitor goes to buy a subscription, they select a plan and Koudoku checks to see if they are signed in or are a registered user and it prompts them to log-in or sign-up.  Sort of a standard 2-step purchase process.  Once they've done that, it redirects them to the checkout page where they can enter their credit card information to purchase the plan they clicked on originally.

If I add in a devise standard after_sign_in_path_for(resource) method, to redirect them to the dashboard after they log-in, it breaks the purchase process if they're not already logged-in.  They get redirected to the dashboard after they log-in even if they've just picked a plan and were prompted to log-in.  They then have to go back to the plans page and pick a plan again.

How do I redirect existing users and subscription owners to the dashboard after log-in, unless they are in the process of purchasing a plan??

Comment: It's really hard to debug a verbal description of code... how about you show us what you tried (even though it isn't working), and we can then help you alter it to do what you need it to do. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by requiring my visitors to become users first before they can view the pricing page and select a plan.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Rails session variable to solve this. Whenever a user selects a plan, you should save the user purchase status(a boolean value) in a session variable. So after login you can check the session variable to conditionally redirect the user to target page.

Don't worry, you can override Devise 'after_sign_in_path_for(resource)' method for conditional redirect. Refer [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-after-a-successful-sign-in-or-sign-out)